# Proper way of including a .h file and portability

Tags: c, include, portability

I would like to include "curl.h" in my C file, but I noticed that curl.h appears in "/usr/include/curl/curl.h"

This leaves me with two options. I can either use (option 1): `#include <curl/curl.h>` or (option 2) `#include <curl.h>`
and compile with `-I/usr/include/curl/`

Besides, `pkg-config --cflags libcurl` returns an empty result, so assuming I want to use pkg-config to generates my compilation option, the right choice seems to be the first one. However, I'm a bit concerned about portability as it's now hardcoded in my program that curl.h has to be in a curl subdir. What do you think?

Comment: Why not include both? That way it will work in both scenarios.

Comment: Many people (including me) would consider the first one to be correct. `/usr/include` is a standard include directory, it's searched automatically by the compiler and its preprocessor, why add flags to search sub-directories?

Comment: equivalent to f.e. <sys/types.h>